# Why ajax response doesn't work?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

I have a `.php` script like this:

```
$arr   =  array();
$arg1  =  $_GET['arg1'];
$arg2  =  $_GET['arg2'];

if ($arg1 !==1 && $arg2 !==0) {
  $arr['msg'] = 'wrong values!';
  header('Content-Type: application/json');     
  echo json_encode($arr);
  exit();
}

$arr['msg'] = 'correct values!';

header('Content-Type: application/json');       
echo json_encode($arr);
```

And here is my `.js` file:

```
$.ajax({
    url :  file.php,
    type : 'GET',
    data : {"arg1": 1, "arg2": 1},
    dataType : 'JSON',
    success : function (data) {
        alert(data.msg);
    }
});
```

As I expect, after executing those code, it should shows a alert containing this message: `wrong values!`. But it doesn't work, Why?

**Note1:** If I pass `data : {"arg1": 1, "arg2": 0}`, It will show a alert containing `correct values!` as well. Now I think the problem is that `if`-statement in the `.php` file.

**Note2:** The above code worked fine already. But now I updated my Xampp and after updating that problem has occurred.

Comment: Unless `arg1` is `1` and `arg2` is `0`, you will always get it showing 'wrong values'.

Comment: @Jon Yes exactly, What you said is what I need. But I don't know why that message `wrong velues` never work ...

Comment: so try an `OR` - `if ($arg1 !==1 || $arg2 !==0)` if that was the intention.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish then, or what's wrong? The response is working fine, and returns the correct values based on the logic in your code.... so what is wrong?

Comment: How do we know what you are expecting. Code shown is working properly. Provide proper explanation of your expectations

Comment: @Fred-ii- The problem isn't related with the condition. That's fine. The problem is `success` doesn't work when that `if`-statement is `true`.

Comment: Then try a reverse method `if ($arg1 ==1 && $arg2 ==1)` and handle the wrong value alert in an `else{...}` (edited to be both 1).

Comment: @Jon **Problem:** When `{"arg1": 1, "arg2": 1}` nothing happens. *(I expect to see a alert containing this message: `wrong values!`)*

Comment: Is your ajax call sends to server? have you check url is with quotes `"{url}"`.

Comment: Then @Fred-ii- comment is **exactly right**: You should change it from an AND `&&` to an OR `||`

Comment: @cale_b and someone's just feeding off it below lol *meh,* let them.

Comment: Also note that http parameters are transmitted as strings and php keeps them as strings. You're using !==, i.e. strict comparison including type checks ,  `'1'!==1` is true.

Comment: ^ true - my `if ($arg1 !==1 || $arg2 !==0)` should have read as `if ($arg1 !=1 || $arg2 !=0)` OP has enough to go on now, given the comments/answers. Nonetheless, still an `OR`. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More or less just putting together all the comments:

- instead of $arg1...&&$arg2... use the logical-or operator
- _GET contains strings (and arrays) and !== checks the data type first, hence $_GET['foo']!==1 will never be true

Because php's implicit [type-juggling](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.type-juggling.php) might consider values equal to 0 or 1 other than you'd expect, I'd suggest you keep the strict comparison (=== or !==).
You apparently want to check some numbers, so I threw [intval()](http://docs.php.net/intval) in and kept the strict comparison. But you could instead test `if ('1'!==$_GET['arg1'] || '0'!==$_GET['arg2'])`.

```
<?php
if ( !isset($_GET['arg1'], $_GET['arg2']) ) {
    $response = [
        'status'=>'error',
        'msg'=>'missing parameter(s)'
    ];
}
else {
    // you could add another test like http://docs.php.net/ctype_digit here first
    $arg1 = intval($_GET['arg1']);
    $arg2 = intval($_GET['arg2']);

    if ( 1!==$arg1 || 0!==$arg2 ) {
        $response = [
            'status' => '...',
            'msg' => 'wrong values!'
        ];
    }
    else {
        $response = [
            'status' => '...',
            'msg' => 'correct values!'
        ];
    }
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');     
echo json_encode($arr);
```

---side note---
I could make an argument for something like

```
$arguments = [
  intval($_GET['arg1']), // maybe even 'arg1'=>intval($_GET['arg1'])
  intval($_GET['arg2'])
];
if ( array(1,0)!==$arguments ) {
```

....but no, I just mention it ;-)

Comment: Just to point out a really small flaw in the code... everything other than the parameters not being set returns "wrong values" ^^

Comment: Haha, it's easy enough to miss, but someone may read it and miss the distinction between the two is all. =]

Answer (score 1):

Your if statement states that *arg1 must not be 1* **and** *arg2 must not be 0*.
When you pass data for arg1=1 and arg2=1 that statement will not work. Your problem is in your if statement. If you want your if statement work for each condition you should use **or** statement like this ||

```
if ($arg1 !==1 || $arg2 !==0) {//i made this condition *or* check this 
  $arr['msg'] = 'wrong values!';
  header('Content-Type: application/json');     
  echo json_encode($arr);
  exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want || (or), not && (and), in your conditional. As currently written, it will return an error only if **both** values are incorrect.